# <br> not rendered in jsp in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, firefox, browser

I have a long text with several paragraph. In order to show it in jsp page I replaced newline with `<br>`.
Now everything shows correctly in Chrome, but NOT in Firefox.

In firefox, only the first several paragraph are rendered correctly with `<br>`, but the later paragraphs are put together as if there is no `<br>` there although there are as I viewed the source code.

Does anyone has an idea about this issue?

by the way, the text is correct in Chrome, but it reacts very slow if I scroll it.

The only browser that works perfect is the eclipse build-in browser, completely no problem there.

Comment: can we see some code? screenshots, fiddle etc

Comment: `<br>` is supported in all browsers so the issue is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding the "br" into the JS output code where you want the paragraph gaps, couldn't you add a class to each of the "p" tags instead and apply a "margin-bottom: 10px;" to that class?

Simple example

JS

```
document.write("<p class='paragraph'>This is the paragraph</p>");
document.write("<p class='paragraph'>This is the paragraph</p>");
document.write("<p class='paragraph'>This is the paragraph</p>");
```

CSS

```
.paragraph {
margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: yeah you are right, this solution is better and more consistent. Thanks!